# Reset the password of an admin account

Tags: admin, password

I recently inherited a project in Craft from another developer, but he's moved on and no one knows what his admin password was.

I've tried generating a password on an account with a fresh install and copying that over the hashed password in MySQL without success.  Are there any other options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can access the users table, change the admin email to yours, then just use the forgot password link