# Unable to change password

Tags: admin, password

I am unable to change my password, as an admin in the CP of Craft.
I tried resetting it but it did not work.

Comment: Please try to be more specific. The community would not be able to help you in any way, unless you provide mode details, such as, what error were you presented (if any), did the email go out etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the email address **is not** yours, follow [these instructions...](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22594/reset-the-password-of-an-admin-account)

If the email address **is** yours, then your local system probably isn't sending out email. Follow [these instructions](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/13966/45) to manually set the password.